# What's the shelf life on crushed specialty grains?

Tags: specialty-malt, ingredients, storage

What's the shelf life on crushed specialty grains?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

3 weeks, maybe longer of you keep them in humidity free environment.

buy yourself a half pound of crystal 60L.  Tatse it each day for a few weeks.  The crisp crunch will fade soon as the grain sucks up moisture.

Comment: +1 I'm gonna vote you up, just cuz it's a good answer. And stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you keep them dry, like in a big rubbermaid container, they should be good for a few months. It's best to keep them uncrushed, and then crush when needed.

Comment: Months is too long for crushed grain.  Down voted because this site needs more downvoting and users to keep it interesting.

Comment: No worries. Take me down!

Comment: Actually, I have a puking 9 week old at home and I'm taking it out on you.  :(

Comment: I understand. You can actually just blame me.

Comment: I upvoted you because I think you're cool and want to be your friend